# Find and replace digits not in brackets in Notepad++

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I have a Latex document that looks like

```
Hello, my figure \ref{figure1} has an ecuation $e=mc^2$ with a mass of 10.5Kg or 20.5 Kg.
```

I want to use the siunitx package, so my goal is to convert the text to

```
Hello, my figure \ref{figure1} has an ecuation $e=mc^2$ with a mass of \SI{10.5}{Kg} or \SI{20.5}{Kg}.
```

How can I find any digits with or without decimal places, followed by a word with or without an empty space between them.  Find only those that are not between {} or $$. Replace the match with \SI{digit found}{word after digit}

Any suggestions would be helpfull. Ideally using notepad++ but open to use Python, Sed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `(?<!\{)(?<!\$)\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!=\})(?!=\$)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)`
Replace with: `\\SI{$1}{$2}`

Comment: Thanks, Still finds matches with \ref{figure12ecuation}, but the rest is very useful! Can you please edit to add an extra backslash: \\SI{$1}{$2}

Comment: @katutxakurra: You can add a word-boundary `\b` before the digits, see my edit. I've also add a double backslash.